# How to enable/disable oracle job using job id

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using following query to enable the oracle job:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.disable('23');
```

where '23' is my Job id. But this seems to be not working for id. I read that, job name should be given in place of '23'. But my job does not have name. It has only Id.
So how to enable it using job Id? any other command to execute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

older DBMS_JOBS had IDs, not scheduler ones. ie you may want this(if your seeing your job in DBA_JOBS view):

```
begin
  dbms_job.broken(23, true);
  commit;
end;
/
```